# Is there a sophisticated file system monitor for Java which is freeware or open source?

Tags: java, file-monitoring

I'm looking for a Java library which can notify me about changes on the file system.

I found some free libraries, but they all use brute-force detection, i.e. polling in regular intervals. And the other ones are always commercial.

What I'm looking for is a library which uses the file monitor functions from the OS, i.e. 
[FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx) for Win32, [FAM](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/FAM) for Linux and whatever is available on other OS. I don't mind if brute-force is used as fallback, but for Windows and Linux it should use the available OS features.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is a programming site. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Java 7 introduced [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) seems to do what you require.

Polling a filesystem (say, a directory for update time changes) won't impose a significant load on your system, and shouldn't be discounted. Apps like Tomcat etc. use this for managing hot deploys with few problems.

It's not a lot of help now, but the upcoming Java 7 has a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) precisely for this.

Answer (score 7):

If you are comfortable working on the bleeding edge of Java, have a look at [JSR 203: More New I/O APIs](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=203) aka nio2 which is due out in **Java 7**.

> A new filesystem interface that
>   supports bulk access to file
>   attributes, **change notification**,
>   escape to filesystem-specific APIs,
>   and a service-provider interface for
>   pluggable filesystem implementations;

Answer (score 6):

[jpathwatch](http://jpathwatch.wordpress.com) is another option. It implements Java 7′s API for directory monitoring, so it is easy to port to Java 7 if desired.

Answer (score 4):

Why does it have to be Java?

The Library that is going to use platform specific API must have native code, so essentially the library is going to be wrappers around the native code that makes the usage of the different APIs transparent.

I suggest if you do not find the Library your self then you will have to either use brute force as you call it, or call the native API using JNI for each platform.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what such a library would be, a wrapper. But I was hoping that something like that already exists. (It exists, but not free/open source)

Answer (score 0):

Two more options that *currently* use polling:

- [Apache Camel File Component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)
- [Spring Integration File Watcher](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#files)

However, because both projects have large active communities, they will likely be updated in the future to support the Java 7 WatchService ([FileSystem.newWatchService()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#newWatchService%28%29)), which **does** use the underlying platform's notification facilities, if any.

Both libraries also provide a useful abstraction layer for integrating with various other transports and systems, so that your main application code is not dependent on the inputs being received from a filesystem.

Comment: A comment explaining the downvote would be helpful...