# java sftp & ftp client library that support file and dir monitoring

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

Please recommend me some java client library for sftp and ftp that support directory monitoring.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The most complete is probably Jakarta Commons Net: http://commons.apache.org/net/

Comment: does it have the folder and file monitoring functionality ?

Thanks

Comment: Robin, AFAIK the Commons Net doesn't have file monitoring support, but if you need this functionality, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096404/is-there-a-sophisticated-file-system-monitor-for-java-which-is-freeware-or-open-s

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

There is no [FTP command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands) for monitoring a directory. Your application will need to connect, request  the directory listing and cache it. Then, periodically, connect, fetch a new listing, and compare it to the cached listing.

Note that FTP servers generally will not let you sit there with an idle connection. So, the proper behavior is to disconnect between checks of the listing.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source library [rdp4j](https://github.com/drapostolos/rdp4j/) which allows to poll for any remote directory.

All that you have to do is to implement adapter for reading from FTP or SFTP server.

Answer (score -1):

[edtFTPj/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/overview.html) is a commercial Java client library that supports SFTP, FTP and FTPS (and SCP).

As another answer notes, you will need to periodically compare the latest listing with the previous one (disconnecting in between attempts).