# How can I tell if a file was renamed?

Tags: java

I have a program monitors log file changes. The program uses a FileInputStream to keep reading from the file. In the mean while, the log file might be rotated: the old log file is renamed and new log entries are written into a new file.

How can my program determines the file was rename so that it switch to read on the new log file?

Comment: Unless you're monitoring the file system for change events you really can't. What file system/platform are you developing for?

Comment: will renaming succeed if the file is opened and actively read from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a sophisticated file system monitor for Java which is freeware or open source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096404/is-there-a-sophisticated-file-system-monitor-for-java-which-is-freeware-or-open-s)

Comment: Similar question with valuable answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494869/file-changed-listener-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1096404/15619) [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) sseems to be the perfect solution to your problem :

> JNotify is a java library that allow java application to listen to file system events, such as:
>
> File created
>
> File modified
>
> File renamed
>
> File deleted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can [watch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) the file system and make changes according to your needs.

Comment: Yes, but only if he's using Java 7. The `java.nio.file` package doesn't exist in Java 6 or earlier.

Comment: In fact there are backports for java.nio.file, like this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1096404/15619) answers mentions

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is simply to poll for the file size every 5 seconds or something like that.

If the file you are reading from was renamed and a new one was created, then your polling will show a sudden decrease in size. You can then recreate you FileinputStream accordingly.

Comment: JNotify and java.nio.file sound good, but for my case polling for file size is more simple.

Comment: Finally we switched to JNotify. It's more reliable than polling for file size. If the old file was empty, file rotation can't be detected by comparing size.